# Style border-image svg (colors) from CSS?

Tags: css, svg, border

Is it possible to style fill custom border-image from the css? 
Which property should I use?

E.g.

```
border-image-source:url('assets/images/dots_new.svg');
border-color: red; /* doesn’t work */
fill: red; /* doesn’t work */
```

Comment: Can you do this inside your svg? You may need to select and style the correct classes inside of your svg.

Comment: I doubt it...essentially it's a `background-image` isn't it...and you can't style the contents of a bg image...right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible.  The SVG is an external file and cannot be styled from the CSS in your page.

The best you can do is add the styling as a `<style>` block in your SVG.  But of course, that means that you have to have one SVG file per colour combination.