# image-border with svg - fill

Tags: html, css, svg, border-image

i have an element which is styled using an image-border using SVG.
I would like to change the color of the SVG using CSS.
The normal fill:color attribute works with direct paths and svg elements, but i can't manage to change the color of the image-border using fill.

my current code:

```
<div class="test">
test
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.test{
border-image-source: url("dots.svg");
border-width: 0 0 8px 0;
border-image-slice: 29% 29%; 
border-image-repeat: round;

fill: green;
}
```

How can i change the SVG color in image-border?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with what is effectively a background image only *inline* SVG - See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/modify-svg-fill-color-when-being-served-as-background-image

Comment: In any case, the `fill` property is being applied to the `div` not the image in your CSS.

Comment: ..and - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062089/style-border-image-svg-colors-from-css

Comment: @Paulie_D fill is inherited. If the svg was inside the div, it would receive the style. Which it isn't with border-image

Comment: guess i will just have to use js to generate the svg then. thanks for the links